# GET http://www.localhost:51644/users net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - $http angular request error

Tags: android, asp.net, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

im trying to do a simple communication between asp.net localhost(visual studio express 2013) to an ionic webapp(currectly testing on my PC, not on phone) vi angular following by this tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http

but i keep getting this error:
GET http://www.localhost:51644/users net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

i also get this error: GET file:///C:/Users/Matan/tabapp/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  but i've been told its beacause im testing on my PC and not on the android device.

the same code in my project is the same code in the $http tutorial.
any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add WWW just use localhost:51644/users unless you have www.localhost set in you hosts file.

The 404 for cordova.js is normal in browser.

Comment: FYI - I received this error when attempting to connect to a firebase.com database and I added the http: portion of the URL when it only wants the \\[dbname].firebaseio.com. Removing the first portion made the error go away.